# Check row if exist in csv Python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I'm new to Python and I'm copying a website and storing it in a csv file, but I can't verify that it exists in the csv file. I imagine that the correct thing would be to scroll through the lines to check if the title already exists. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? See the code below:

```
from pathlib import Path
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

DRIVER_PATH = str(Path('geckodriver').resolve())


def write_csv(ads):
    filename = 'results.csv'
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        fields = ['title', 'url']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)
        existing_lines = csv.reader(f)
        for ad in ads:
            if ad['title'] not in existing_lines:
                print(existing_lines)
                writer.writerow(ad)
               
                print('success')
            else:
                print('fail')


def get_html(url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    browser.get(url)
    return browser.page_source


def scrapde_data(card):
    try:
        h2 = card.h2
    except:
        title = ''
        url = ''
    else:
        title = h2.text.strip()

    try:
        url = card.find('a').get('href')
    except:
        url = ''

    data = {'title': title, 'url': url}

    return data


def main():
    while True:
        url = '#'
        html = get_html(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        cards = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "produto--comprar"})

        ads_data = []

        for card in cards:
            data = scrapde_data(card)
            ads_data.append(data)
            write_csv(ads_data)

        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Help me please? :(

Comment: Maybe write to a database table using title as primary key and dropping rows where already present.

Comment: Do you know any possibilities to improve this code so that it goes through the csv list without database?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:-

```
def write_csv(ads):
    
    filename = 'results.csv'
    with open(filename, 'a+', newline='') as f:
        fields = ['title', 'url']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)

        #moving file pointer at the start of the file
        f.seek(0)
        existing_lines = csv.reader(f)
        
        #finding no of lines in the file
        count=0
        for line in existing_lines:
            count+=1
            break

        #if file is not empty
        if count>0:
            for ad in ads:
                flag=0

                #moving file pointer to the start of the file
                f.seek(0)

                #checking if ad['title'] is present in the first column of csv file
                for line in existing_lines:
                    if ad['title'] in line[0]:
                        flag=1 

                #if ad['title'] is not found                   
                if flag==0:
                    writer.writerow(ad)
        
        #if file is empty write the dictionary contents into the csv
        else:
            for ad in ads:
                writer.writerow(ad)
```

Comment: I'm feeling on top of the world. Thank's bro

Comment: You're welcome!!